# JQuery отказывается понимать json формат[приходит строка, а не объект]

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Пример:
Есть файл .js и .php

В файле .js написано примерно следующее:

```
$.ajax({
   url:"index.php",
   datatype:"json",
   success:function(result){
      console.info(result);
   }
});
```

В файле .php следующее

```
$array = array("object1" => "Boat","object2" => "Car","object3" => "Ship");
echo json_encode($array);
```

P.S Если в файле .js в части блока success написать это: `$objectJson = JSON.parse(result)`, то json строка превратится в json объект, тогда смысл мне было указывать  `datatype: "json"`???

Comment: А что вам приходит с сервера? Посмотрите в браузер консоли.

Comment: приходит строка, а мне нужен объект, вроде бы этим и должен заниматься datatype: "json"

Comment: Добавьте её в вопрос, пожалуйста.

Comment: правильно добавил?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
dataType:"json"
```

T - c большой буквы.

Comment: Точно, я тоже думал об этом, но не придавал этому особое внимание, тогда такой контр вопрос, зачем нужна эта функция JSON.parse();?

Comment: @MaximPro, Лично я не вижу между ними разницы, кроме как в варианте с JSON.parse(); мы можем протестировать полученный результат на что-нибудь перед распарсиванием.

Comment: @MaximPro Учитывайте, что в JavaScript имеет значение регистр полей и переменных. `JSON.parse()` нужен чтобы преобразовывать JSON-строку в объект. Именно эту функцию и вызывает jQuery, когда получает через AJAX JSON с соответствующим Content-Type или когда вы принудительно задаете `dataType: 'json'`

Comment: @tutankhamun я знаю, что функция JSON.parse() преобразовывает из строки в объект так же как и dataType:"json" , но зачем столько вариаций? где здесь смысл?

Comment: @MaximPro Когда вы принудительно указываете `dataType:"json"` jQuery пытается преобразовать ответ в объект при помощи функции `JSON.parse()` даже если придет JSON-строка с `Content-Type: text/html`

Comment: @MaximPro ...а если не указываете `dataType`, тогда смотрит на заголовок `Content-Type` и, в зависимости от того что там написано, применяет соответствующий фильтр. Также в `dataType` может быть указано несколько типов, тогда jQuery также будет смотреть на заголовок

Comment: @tutankhamun это получается что-то вроде функции внутри функции, интересно! где можно почитать о том что вы написали?

Comment: @MaximPro http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ (по-английски) или покопаться в исходниках jQuery

Comment: @tutankhamun спасибо, лучше уж в английской документации)

Answer (score 3):

Ответ сервера должен приходить с правильным заголовком `Content-Type`.

То есть возможно стоит только добавить:

```
header('Content-Type: text/javascript');
```

Или более правильно (согласно [RFC 4627](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt)):

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```